# how to have a trigger work only for certain columns (they are chosen by their id) after updating

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I have two tables.Tickets which has the columns: ticketid,startdate , enddate
and transactions which has the columns: transactionid, ticketid (fk to tickets), ticketcost.I want to create a trigger on tickets that makes a discount to ticketcost of transactions(of the table transactions) whenever the enddate of a ticket is updated.Multiple transactions might have the same ticket.

I was able to make a trigger that did what i described however not only at one ticket, the one that the date was changed, but every ticket of the tickets table.

first attempt:

```
create or replace function changeDate() returns trigger as $changeDate$

    BEGIN
        IF  new.enddate != old.enddate  THEN
            update transactions
            set ticketcost = ticketcost - ticketcost*0.1
            from tickets
            where tickets.ticketid= transactions.ticketid;

        END IF;
        return new;
    END
$changeDate$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER changeDate after UPDATE ON tickets
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION changeDate();
```

This obviously failed because it is done for every row so every ticket is updated.

What i have now is this:

```
create or replace function changeDate() returns trigger as $changeDate$
    Declare
            arg1 integer;
    BEGIN
        IF  new.enddate != old.enddate  THEN
            update transactions
            set ticketcost = ticketcost - ticketcost*0.1
            from tickets
            where arg1 = transactions.ticketid;

        END IF;
        return new;
    END
$changeDate$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER changeDate after UPDATE ON tickets
    FOR EACH ROW 
    WHEN (new.enddate != old.enddate) 
    EXECUTE FUNCTION changeDate(tickets.ticketid);
```

I have been trying to pass only the id of a ticket that has different new and old dates.The query works but nothing is changed.Basically i m trying to find a way to pass the id of the ticket that has had its enddate field changed.In the above example i m trying to pass it as a variable when the condition i described occurs.Any help would be appreciated as i cant really find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [restrict](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) the trigger to fire only when the date has been updated by specifying the column name and by ensuring the updated value is not the same as the old one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER changeDate after UPDATE OF enddate ON tickets
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (OLD.enddateIS DISTINCT FROM NEW.enddate )
EXECUTE FUNCTION changeDate();
```

Inside the trigger function, you can refer to the NEW.ticketID directly

```
create or replace function changeDate() returns trigger as $changeDate$
BEGIN

    update transactions
    set ticketcost = ticketcost - ticketcost*0.1
    where transactions.ticketid = NEW.ticketid;

    return new;
END
$changeDate$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

PS: since the function is not changing the date, a better name would be `setDiscount`

Comment: thanks for the quick and concise answer.I will accept it!